# Angular Routing and Binding data from controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have my angular routing like th below code

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/DeclarationForms/V1/EmployeeProfile.html',
        controller: 'empController'
    }).when('/DeclarationAndIndemnityBond.html', {
        templateUrl: '/DeclarationForms/V1/DeclarationAndIndemnityBond.html',
        controller: 'declarationController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });

    app.controller('empController', function ($scope, $http) {

        var resultPromise = $http.get("../ViewForms/GetData/", { params: { ProcName: "SP_EmployeeProfile_GetList" } });
        resultPromise.success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.employeeProfile = data;
        });
    });
});
```

The `empController` calls my controller action with a parameter as per the code

```
$http.get("../ViewForms/GetData/", { params: { ProcName: "SP_EmployeeProfile_GetList" } });
```

The controller's action code is as follows

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult GetData(string ProcName)
        {
            if(Session["UserJDRECID"]==null || Session["UserJDRECID"].ToString()=="0")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User_Login");
            }
            else
            {
                var UsrJDID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserJDRECID"]);
                DataSet dt = Helper.PopulateData(ProcName, UsrJDID);
                string JSONString = string.Empty;
                JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
                return Json(JSONString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

The form get loaded properly as per the code

```
templateUrl: '/DeclarationForms/V1/EmployeeProfile.html',
```

but it don't call my action `GetData` from where I suppose to bind the `EmployeeProfile.html`

If I change my angular controller like below code this still don't work

```
app.controller('empController', function ($scope) 
{
 console.log("hi"); alert(); 
});
```

My console gives below error

> Error: error:areq
>
> Bad Argument

Please help me I stuck here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As @Bruno suggested, the problem looks with the url which you are calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "../" inside your $http.get. 
I don`t know how your project is setup, but you can try:

```
$http.get("/ViewForms/GetData/", { params: { ProcName: "SP_EmployeeProfile_GetList" } });
```

In that case the ViewForms is the name of your controller and it needs to be in the root or pass the complete url. 
Make sure you are passing all the **folders** then **Controller** then your **action**.

Example: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/1202/angular-http-service-aspnet-mvc

Comment: If I use below codes it still didn't work for me 

`app.controller('empController', function ($scope) {
        console.log("hi");
        alert();
    });`

Comment: You didn`t understand, the problem is the path of the Asp.Net MVC Controller. You are passing a wrong URL.

Answer (score 0):

I change my code as follows and this worked for me.

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/DeclarationForms/V1/EmployeeProfile.html',
            controller: 'empController'
        })
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
    });
});

app.controller('empController', ['$scope', '$http', EmployeeProfile]);
function EmployeeProfile($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("../ViewForms/GetData", { params: { ProcName: "SP_EmployeeProfile_GetList" } })//Done
        .then(function (response) {
            var mydata = $.parseJSON((response.data));
            $scope.employeeProfile = $.parseJSON(mydata);
    });
}
```